# Express <projectname> not working

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have installed express globally using the command

```
npm install -g express-generator@4
```

after which if i am doing 
express .No project is created,surprisingly no errors also.
where is the actual issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the express project is following:

```
$ mkdir myapp
$ cd myapp
$ npm init
entry point: index.js
$ npm install express --save
```

Or:

```
$ npm install express-generator -g
$ express myapp
```

Comment: I tried the same thing,not working,so i asked...
i tried npm install epress-generator -g
express myapp

Answer (score 0):

If we install nodejs from apt-get package manager,we get this issue.
try uninstalling it first,sudo apt-get remove nodejs.
goto nodejs main site and download the source.
Try installing nodejs from source,set the path variable,and there you go.